# Dynamic Slider Tableau Million/Billions

Tags: parameters, tableau-api, calculated-field

I am working with a simple Tableau sheet that takes volumes and dates.

The numbers are quite high so sometimes it goes from millions/billions and I use a slider filter type where I can choose the ranges that I care about.

Unfortunately the values in the slider are too big and I would like to improve readability by having a "B" when the value is billion, "M" when it is million and "K" when it is thousands in the slider.

To do so, first I created some parameters:

1. Billions:

[image]

2. Millions:

[image]

3. Thousands:

[image]

Finally I created a calculated field:

```
if str([Volume]) = str([Billions]) THEN float(replace(str(round([Volume], -9)),"000000000","B"))
ELSEIF str([Volume]) = str([Millions]) THEN float(replace(str(round([Volume], -6)),"000000","M"))
ELSEIF  str([Volume]) = str([Thousands]) THEN float(replace(str(round([Volume], -3)),"000","K"))
else float(str([Volume])) END
```

Unfortunately, this does not work.

Does Anyone have a suggestion on how to reach my desired solution? or a better way to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple parameters create one like this. Name it `TMB`

[image]

Add calculation field(s) (one each for desired measure) like this.. e.g. for `[sales]`

```
[sales]/TMB
```

and you can tweak your measures in the way you wanted them

[image]

[image]